# To prove a condition on the contestants

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

A math contest consists of a Part-1 and a Part-2, with a combined total of 28 questions. Each contestant solved 7 problems altogether. For each pair of problems there were exactly two contestants who had solved both of them . Prove that there was a contestant who in part 1 solved either no problem or at least 4 problems .

In my attempt , I begun by trying to find out the number of contestants.
Let us assume that some problem $A$ was solved by $x$ people.
As each of these $x$ people will have solved 6 other questions, 6$x$ other problems were solved (With repetition).There are 27 problems other than $A$. As each of the others is solved twice, 54 other solutions exist, hence

$6x=54$   so  $x=9$.

That would mean that each problem is solved by 9 people and there are 28 problems .Pair this with the fact that each person solves exactly 7 ,That leaves

$9×28/7 = 36$ contestants

It is not neccecsary that Part-1 and Part-2 have the same number of questions.

This is as far as I could get.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. (There is another way by counting directly the number of resolutions of pairs of problems : if you have $N$ constestants, each solves $7$ problems, so in total $\binom{7}{2} N = 21 N$ pairs of problems were solved, and since each pair is also solved by exactly $2$ contestants, this has to be equal to $2\binom{28}{2} = 28 \cdot 27$ and therefore indeed $N = 4\cdot 9 = 36$. Your way gives, furthermore, the number of contestants who solved one given problem.)

To conclude, assume by contradiction that everyone solved between $1$ and $3$ problems in part 1. (I assume parts 1 and 2 have the same number of problems, $14$, but correct me if this is not a hypothesis.)

The $14$ problems of part 1 were resolved $14 \cdot 9$ times, by $36$ contestants. But $\frac{14 \cdot 9}{36} = \frac{7}{2} = 3.5$. This is impossible if everyone solved less than $4$ problems. (By the way, you prove that there always exists a contestant who solved at least $4$ problems ; the other option "there exists a contestant who solved no problem at all" does not matter.)

EDIT : How to tackle the fact that both part may have a different number of questions : Let $m$ be the number of problems in part 1. By doing the same as above, we can see that if $m > \frac{36}{9} 3 = 12$, then there is a contestant who did at least $4$ problems in part $1$.

Else, $m \leq 12$. Let $n_1, n_2, n_3$ be the number of contestants who did $1$, $2$ or $3$ problems in part 1, respectively. $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = 36$. Then, by counting pairs of problems inside part 1, you see that you must have :

$$ n_2 + n_3 \binom{3}{2} = 2 \binom{m}{2} $$

Furthermore, $n_1 + 2 n_2 + 3 n_3 = 9m$ (each problem is solved by exactly $9$ contestants). Therefore, $n_2 + 2 n_3 = 9m - 36$ and then $n_3 = 2 \binom{m}{2} - 9m + 36 = m^2 - 10m + 36$. Then, you have :

$$ n_2 = 2 \binom{m}{2} - 3 n_3 = -2m^2 + 29m - 108 $$

And finally $n_1 = 36 - n_2 - n_3 = m^2 -19m + 108$.

These are polynomials of second order in $m$. But the polynomial for $n_2$ has $\Delta = 29^2 - 4 \cdot 108 \cdot 2 = -23$ so $n_2 < 0$ for every $m$. This is a contradiction.

(I hope I didn't make any mistake in my computations, please notify me if I did. Actually, I didn't need to distinguish between $m > 12$ and $m \leq 12$.)

Comment: I would like to add that it is not neccecsary that Part-1 and Part-2 have the same number of questions(I missed it in my question, will edit it now). The contradiction method seems fine. May be with this extra bit of info you could tweak your answer a bit and the second option of the proof becomes meaninful. Thank you for the solution .I will try to proceed myself from your hint though, But do edit your answer as well once you are done with it.

Comment: I edited my post. I think the method I use here works, and hopefully the computations are correct.

Comment: Yes they are perfect. Thank you very much.